# jQuery: setting up attribute as variable

Tags: jquery, variables, attributes

I'm trying to set up a variable for elements with the attribute "reference" where the attribute "reference" is equal to the selected image's attribute "protein". I've tried several options, nothing seems to work.

```
    var navig = "attr('reference')"+$(this).attr('protein');
    var navig = "['reference']"+$(this).attr('protein');
    var navig = '[reference]'+$(this).attr('protein');
    var navig = '.selected['reference']+$(this).attr('protein');
```

I'm fairly new at jQuery so sorry if my question is idiotic.

Comment: Have you considered using HTML5s `data-*` attribute? This article can give you a better sense: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Without HTML codes or more detailed description it's hard to give an exact answer.

.attr() is a function so if you use it inside string it has no effect.
[attr=value] is a notation used inside jQuery selector, such as $("div[reference=value]");

If you want to save a jQuery object reference, just catch the return value of jQuery selector.

```
var $references = $("[reference=value]");
```

As long as you know how to select the reference element and the image, you can use attr() to get and set attributes on them.

For example:

```
$("#id-of-reference-element").attr('reference', $("#id-of-image").attr('protein'));
```

basically .attr(attr-name) will return attribute string and .attr(attr-name,new-value) will change that attribute value.

Comment: Thank you World FS. I still didn't get it to work but it help to understand the attributes better.